# How do I use d3.js with a javascript file rather than writing code within the <script> tags in an html file?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

I'm learning d3.js for the first time.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>D3.js??</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
        <script>
            const svg = d3.select('svg');
            svg.style('background-color', 'red');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The HTML above works but when I replace the `script` tags with

```
<script" type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
```

it stops working.

What should the code in my index.js file look like? Currently, it looks like this:

```
import { select } from 'd3';

const svg = select('svg');
svg.style('background-color', 'red');
```

Also, do I have to make any changes to my HTML?

Comment: You need to use the new [module support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) properly: `<script type="module">` for both: https://jsfiddle.net/mnc7o5fu/ (note that it works without modules if you use the exact code of your inline script in the external file)

Comment: i guess u may just use `const svg = d3.select('svg');` instead

Comment: @datdinhquoc good point, and also import * as d3 from 'd3';

Comment: I tried `<script type="module">` but it still isn't working. It works only when my code is in the script tag in the HTML file. I also tried using the exact code of my inline script and it doesn't work

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: The script tag you provided has a typo „ after script ?!

Comment: Oops it probably was that.. It's working now, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I was having the same issue, but you can add this snippet to the head tag

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
```

and link your script file to your html file, then you can do all your d3 stuff in your js file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33981234)